# The subgroup $<S>$ generated by an open subset $S$ of a Lie group $G$ is open in $G$

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, differential-topology

The subgroup $<S>$ generated by an open subset $S$ of a Lie group $G$ is open in $G$.

I was told to prove this using the fact that $<S>= \cup_{g\in<S>}gS$. But this does not feel so right, since $\cup_{g\in<S>}gS$ does not look like a group. Suppose that I have $g_1s_1$, its inverse is $s_1^{-1}g_1^{-1}$, this is not necessarily in $\cup_{g\in<S>}gS$, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $S \ne \emptyset$, and let $s_{0} \in S$

Clearly $\bigcup \{ g S : g \in \langle S \rangle \} \subseteq  \langle S \rangle$, as $ \langle S \rangle$ is a subgroup containing $S$. (Actually the smallest such subgroup.)

Conversely, if $g \in  \langle S \rangle$, then $g = g s_{0}^{-1} s_{0} \in (g s_{0}^{-1}) S$, with $g s_{0}^{-1} \in  \langle S \rangle$.